# matcher in java not yielding desired output

Tags: java, regex

```
nodenName = VAS_DEL_SDC_LB1_ONM_DEL_10.200.98.74;
private String extractNodeName(String nodeName) {
        String output = "";
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(nodeName);
        while (match.find()) {
            output.split(match.group());
        }
        return output;
    }
```

can anybody help me out for extracting only `VAS_DEL_SDC_LB1_ONM_DEL`, the above i tried its not working

Comment: `String.split()` does *not* alter the String (because they are immutable). Instead it returns a *new* `String[]`

Comment: I suggest you @Avinash Raj answer, you can test it [here](http://regexr.com/)... This website is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String extractNodeName(String nodeName) {
        String output = "";
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?<!\\d|_)").matcher(nodeName);
        while (match.find()) {
            output = match.group();
        }
        return output;
}
```

Result:
`VAS_DEL_SDC_LB1_ONM_DEL`

Comment: Thank you so much Kerwin ... its working
can you please explain compile("\\w+(?<!\\d|_)")
how does it work

Comment: it match letters and the end is not number or `_`

Comment: `(?<!\\d|_)` Assert that it is impossible to match the `\\d|_` below

Comment: if I am considering something like this KOL_SDC_APP_KOL-MT-SMSRAPP3_10.6.227.60 
then output is coming as SMSRAPP but I want the output as KOL_SDC_APP_KOL-MT-SMSRAPP3
for this how do I need to modify compile("\\w+(?<!\\d|_)")

Comment: for your two example , seems you want get subString from start to the last `_`,  use this `[\\w-]+(?=_)`  replace old one. And I think you only need `nodenName.substring(0, nodenName.lastIndexOf("_"))`

Answer (score 1):

Just match all the chars upto the first `_` which exist before a digit.

```
String output = "";
Matcher match = Pattern.compile(".*?(?=_[0-9])").matcher(nodeName);
while(match.find())
{
  output = m.group();
}
return output;
```

Comment: compiled it,
match value is coming  as
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*?(?=_[0-9]) region=0,36 lastmatch=]
output is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static String extractNodeName(String nodeName) {
    return nodeName.replaceAll("[\\d_.]{2,}", "");
}
```